# How to apply format to step name in allure json result file

Tags: python, selenium, allure, python-behave

I have next scenario:

```
  Scenario: Add new user admin with valid data
    When I visit "User" page
    And click "Add user" button
    And specify "{random_name}" as admin name
    And specify "{random_email}" as admin email
    And specify "{random_phone}" as admin phone number in proper format
    ...
    And click "Save" button
```

And I apply format to change value in step (e.g. `context.step.name = context.step.name.format(random_name=user_name)`)

When I look on generated behave xml report I can see that {parameter_name} was formatted

[image]

But when I open allure json result file format was not applied. 
[image]
[image]

**Q:** How this can be implemented? What I miss? May be some extra method should be specified in hooks after step?

P.S.: even with ReportPortal.io it works perfectly.

Also tried to investigate https://pypi.org/project/pytest-allure-adaptor/ "Steps" block, but no luck :(